# jQuery Enlarge Effect - First Run Different then Others

Tags: jquery, css

this is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/shaharlini/Nd5Q6/1/

as you see the first time acts different than the other time.

I'm trying to achieve the effect after the first run.

```
 $("div.square").animate({

            height: "+=50",
            width: "+=50",
            top: -25,
            left: -25

        },timespan);
        $("div._sis").animate({
            top:"+=25",
            left: "+=25"
        },timespan);


    }
```

P.S. I didn't want to add the full code since jsfiddle is much easier, and stackoverflow require me to add some code.

Thanks Devs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add that css to class `.square`

```
 top:0px;
left:0px;
```

See example : **[JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Nd5Q6/3/)**

Comment: Thanks! that worked like a charm.. I never thought it was caused by the .square